# Seed |sample operator in ADX?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

"|sample x" is used in ADX to retrieve x random samples/rows from a table. Is there a way to make the sampling consistent? Or seed its randomness so it selects the same rows each time rather than outputting a different set of rows each time it is called?

This code will pull 2 random rows from data each time it is executed:

```
let data=datatable(timestamp:datetime, metric: real)
[
  datetime(2017-01-01), 1,
  datetime(2017-01-02), 2,
  datetime(2017-01-03), 3,
  datetime(2017-01-04), 4,
  datetime(2017-01-05), 5,
  datetime(2017-01-06), 6,
];
data
| sample 2
```

Is it possible to keep pulling the same two random rows, each time this query is executed?

Answer (score 0):

sample is a non-deterministic operator, and will return different result set each time it is evaluated during the query. For example, the following query yields two different rows (even if one would expect to return the same row twice). There is no way to "seed" this function or ADX's rng.

What may be helpful is using `|take 2` if only consistency is required or using a Python solution which can run in Kusto by using [ADX's Python plugin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/pythonplugin?pivots=azuredataexplorer).